# Using raspberry pi 2 W with ADS1015, after taking analog reading and copying value to another object the value changes in original object

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, i2c, raspberry-pi-zero

```
#create class of Voltage readings
class Reading:
    def __init__(self, name, value, voltage, test):
        self.name = name
        self.value= value #decimal value of 10 bit resolution value after taking reading
        self.voltage = voltage #measured voltage after taking reading
        self.test = test #True = passed test, False = failed test
        
PS1 = Reading("PS1", 0, 0.0, False)


def Test_1():
    
    
    #turn on main power and test power supplies
    
    t_begin = datetime.now() #take timestamp for referance to beginning of test
    GPIO.output(Sim_Main_Pwr, True)  # turn on main power by activating relay K8
    time.sleep(1)  # delay 2 seconds for stabilization

    #take a reading of Power supply 1 voltage
    i2cbus.write_byte(TCA_addr, 0b00000001)  # select channel on the i2c mux
    PS1_V = AnalogIn(ads, PS1_ADS) # read information to ads object from pin 2 of ADS1015
    print("PS1_V : " , PS1_V) 
    print("PS1_V : " , PS1_V.value) 
    print("PS1_V : " , PS1_V.voltage) 
    
    PS1.value = PS1_V.value
    PS1.voltage = PS1_V.voltage
    
    print("PS1_V : " , PS1_V) 
    print("PS1_V : " , PS1_V.value) 
    print("PS1_V : " , PS1_V.voltage) 
    
    print("PS1 : " , PS1) 
    print("PS1 : " , PS1.value) 
    print("PS1 : " , PS1.voltage)
```

after executing this snippet of code the following is the output:
[image]

At first the original .value and .voltage changed drastically but now the values are only changing a little bit. I don't understand what changed besides I am now printing them out. There is probably a better way to put the AnalogIn.value and AnalogIn.voltage into the class Reading i created but it works as it is besidesthe original value changing a bit now.

I tried to change the way I passed the values to the class Reading I created but couldn't figure out a better way to do that. So I am still going to use the intermediary object to hold the values in the AnalogIn(ads, PS1_ADS) line of code and then pass the values after.

Don't know why the original object PS1_V voltage and value changed after copying the values over to PS1 and if it is a concern. Could the PS1 values change later?

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow! Maybe you should [read this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557), and then edit your question.

Comment: @diegoBorba that didn't answer my question...

Comment: What makes you think the python programming community knows what an ADS1015 device is and how it operates.  There is clerly more going on than what your code snippet shows, please clarify your problem.

Comment: @itprorh66 all my question is about is how the data stored in the PS1_V object could change after copying that data to another object. And also why the object that the data was copied to (PS1) doesn't exactly match either the before or after copied object's data.